# Switch global proxy configuration in OS X

Tags: osx-lion, proxy

I am using OS X Lion. Sometimes and depending on whether I am home or work I need to change the whole proxy and specify a socks one. This can be done by hand obviously but I wonder whether I could assing this to some shortcut or easier procedure.

Comment: Couldn't you just use different network locations under *System Preferences » Network » Location*?

Comment: how could I easily switch among them?

Comment: You just define multiple locations, one for home, one for work, and specify the proxies for each. Then you switch the location through System Preferences or by going to * » Location*.